# Read file / match string / replace part of the string with user input / write file

Tags: python

Reading the million resources around the web, I'm getting more confused than helped, as I believe that there are many ways to do what I need to do with py.

So I hope some of you python gurus can lend me a hand.

What I need to do is the following:

- Prompt user for input [INPUT]
- Open an html file (simple, nothing too big)
- Search for `<a target="_top" href="http://website">Local website</a>`
- Replace `http://website` (which is never the same string) with [INPUT]
- Write the file (as the same file opened)

Now, if I understand correctly I should use regex within python, is this correct?

My pseudo code (sorry, I know it looks terrible) would be:

```
var = raw_input("Enter input: ")
print var, "will be the new site"

import re
o = open("test.html","w")
data = open("test.html").read()
o.write( re.sub("<a target="_top" href="(*)">Local website</a>",var,data) )
o.close()
```

The above is probably not even the best way to do this, but it works without the regex part, doing a simple match-replace (where the match is always the same).

Any hint from you folks?

Comment: Your code looks quite good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good. I just changed a little bit. I wasn't super clear on what your question was since your code seems to be functional. Hope it helps:

```
import re

INFILE = 'test.html'
OUTFILE = 'replaced.html'

new_site_name = raw_input('Enter input: ')
print new_site_name, 'will be the new site.'

pattern = '<a .* href="(.+)">.+</a>'
replacement = '<a target="_top" href=%s>Local website</a>'  % new_site_name

with open(INFILE, 'r') as f:
    html_text = f.read()

with open(OUTFILE, 'w') as f:
    f.write(re.sub('<a .* href="(.+)">.+</a>', replacement, html_text))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel! 
Your code looks quite different compared to mine so I guess I was going the wrong way, especially for the regex part. 
Legend, thanks again!